# error add money from all records - count()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

i need to add up all the money in the column "ingresos".

Error: **Property [presupuesto] does not exist on this collection instance.**

used the variable
:

```
{{ $contador->presupuesto->count() }}
```

database:

[image]

Controller:

```
public function contador(){

        if (Auth::guest()) return redirect('/login');

      

        $contador = \App\Models\Registro::All();
       
        return view('contador',compact('contador'));
   


    }
```

I need to add the income

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You count the values, but you have to add them . To calculate the sum of values, use:

```
$contador->sum('presupuesto');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the document https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#aggregates for such transactions.

As for your question, you should use the `sum` function.

```
$contador->sum('presupuesto')
```

Answer (score 0):

You got this `Error: Property [presupuesto] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Because by `\App\Models\Registro::All()` you'll get a collection and you need to iterate over it to get its properties. The `count()` is when you want to get to number of rows in a collection. But you want to get the sum, as it already mentioned by the other answers you need to use `sum()`.